# How to append hover on the svg in react component

Tags: reactjs, svg, text, hover, tooltip

Currently I have legend, which display the text below the rect but I want the text to appear only when I hover over the rect. I tried using mouseover and css hover but nothing seems to work. Also mouseOver event is called when I click and not on hovering.

I read some post which suggest something like this :

```
svg text {display: none;}
svg g:hover text {display: block;}
```

But currently I have my code in this format written in react, so how to hover to the g ?

I have shared part of my code below :

```
// creating svg
selectedLegend
.append("svg")
.attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${count} 1`)
.attr("preserveAspectRatio", "none")

function legend(g: any) {
// appending data
g.selectAll("g.legendCells")
.data(itemColor)
.enter()
.append("rect");
// appending text for label, which is not working as expected
g.selectAll("g")
.style("background-color", "grey")
.append("text")
.attr("class", "breakLabels")
.style("font-size", "0.4")
.attr("x", function (d: any, i: any) {
return i + "." + 25
})
.attr("y", 1.5)
.text(function (d: Record<string, unknown>, i: any) {
})
}
```

I tried adding like this both on svg and rect but did not work

```
.on("mouseover", function (e: any) {
// tried with this also
//select(e.target).style("display", "block")
})
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/s6f7z3p4/3/

**Note:**

```
<style>
svg text {display: none;}
svg g:hover text {display: block;}
</style>
```

If I add above style in fiddle it works fine but how can I use above style in my react component since it do not support style tag. I am facing issue in adding :hover to the svg(g), since it cannot be added as style or neither as attr

Comment: Where's the javascript in the jsfiddle?

Comment: Its an very long code and I am not sure how can I show that in fiddle because it has if condition and so on . But have shared part of code above in the question. Basically the label 0,1,2,3 which u see in fiddle should appear on hover over the rect.

Comment: You need to cut it down to an [mcve] ideally [in the question itself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) rather than a jsfiddle.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I append hover to g, so that it must be like g:hover, because I append text and style like this .attr() or .style() but not sure about hover